# How can I debug an InfoPath VersionUpgrade method?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, infopath

I inherited an InfoPath form and need to add some more logic to the `VersionUpgrade` method, to convert old forms to an updated schema.

The previous caretaker had to resort to deploying the form and spitting out information via MessageBox.Show.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked on any VersionUpgrade methods myself, but if you go to File->Form Options->Preview, you can specify a file to use as the starting file in preview mode. If you do that and run the code in debug mode, I reckon you could walk the code in the debugger, but would that suit your scenario?

Comment: One caveat for others: `XmlForm.New` is set to `true` when using this feature, which is not the case when published and an existing form is opened.